# Check if label exists in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an ajax jquery function that populates an array with each element containing a label and value:

```
    var accountOptions = new Array();
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: apiUrl+"/Accounts/GetDropdown",
            async: false,
            success:
            function (response) {
                    $.each(response.Data, function (i, item) {
                        accountOptions.push({ label: item.Number, value: item.Id })
                    });
            }
    });
```

This function works fine, but I need to check if a label exists in this array and cannot find how to do this. I tried this function, but it checks the array to see if a value exists and not the label.

```
if ($.inArray(account, accountOptions) == -1)
    {
        $(this).addClass("validation-error");
        alert("This account does not exist.");
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what type are label and value (it looks like both are number or maybe value is a string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use jquery [grep](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/) which makes a new array with whatever filter you set. If the length is >0 then it exists.

```js
var array=[{'label':'one','value':'two'},{'label':'other','value':'more'},{'label':'foo','value':'bar'}];

var matches=$.grep(array,function(n){
  return n.label=='foo';
});
if(matches.length==0)
  alert('this account does not exist');
else
  alert('this account exists');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I found this answer clever so I looked into it. It turns out it may actually be more efficient to just use a for loop. https://jsperf.com/jquery-grep-vs-for-loop

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/uwhgooeg/

```
var accountOptions = [{
    label: "account",
    value: 0
},
{                
    label: "label 2",
    value: 1
}
];

var account = "account";
for(var i = 0; i < accountOptions.length; i++){
    if(accountOptions[i].label == account)
    {
        $(this).addClass("validation-error");
        alert("This account does not exist.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

since you have an array of objects I would probably just loop through quick to see if it is there and grab it if it is.

```
function labelExists(lblval) {
  for(i=0; i<accountOptions.length; i++) {
    if (accountOptions[i].value == lblval) { 
      return accountOptions[i];
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

This probably isn't the best if you data set gets too large.